# Git: Is it ok to merge master into a sub branch?

Tags: git

I am working on a sub branch of my git repository. I've been working on it for a while aswell as other branches which I've merged with the master branch and put live. So there will be a lot of conflicts to fix once I'm finished on my sub branch and merge it into the master.

My question is, while I'm working on my sub branch, woud it be ok to merge the latest master branch into it so I can starting addressing conflicts? And then in the future when I'm finished with the sub branch, merge it into the master branch for final release?

I'm sure this is ok but want to check that I am going about this the correct way.

Hope I'm making sense :)

Answer (score 1):

The better way might be using `git rebase` from the master branch every now and then and merge the changes into the master branch when ready.

This workflow, its benefits and pitfalls are described in [this post](http://randyfay.com/content/rebase-workflow-git).

*TL;DR*: the commit history will be much cleaner, but rebasing must be used cautiously (do not rebase the publicly exposed branches).

Answer (score 0):

When you work on a feature branch you can merge your master in your branch to get the latest version. In most cases you work longer on a feature branch and need some feature from your master to prevent trouble.